# No sound in Flash videos

Tags: sound, flash

Even though I can play Flash videos on most sites. It's been going on. Tried to install Flash manually and with Flash aid help but nothing. I'm running 12.04 LTS, But I had the same problem with 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Chrome...
Because the flash support for linux has been withdrawn and now google administers it for linux so chrome is a must and everything will go fine... :)

Comment: that's really not the answer i was looking for. Guess it'll have to do for now. What about gnash?

Comment: Well even I am facing problems with gnash.
The default gnome web browser "Epiphany" uses Gnash as the primary flash support but as i said no flash content is displayed in it.
So as of now chrome seems the solution.
or you may try to remove(purge to be safer) flash plugin and reinstall it.

Comment: this didn't work...

Comment: Then you should consider reinstalling the plugin

Comment: I've did that twice, and still nothing... :/

Comment: okay..!!
Try this link...
http://blogdaprima.com/2012/install-adobe-flash-plugin-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/

Comment: Here is anoter link
http://www.noobslab.com/2012/02/no-adobe-flash-on-linux-except-chrome.html

Comment: Nirmik, that last link worked! Even though the font on the youtube player isn't quite the best, it solved it for me! (LIGHTSPARK!). It doesn't work in the best way, but it DOES have sound...

Comment: :D
I am glad it worked..!!
:)

Happy Video(with audio) Streeming..!! ;)
dont 4gt to tick as answered :p

Comment: If its a problem of only YOUTUBE...you could try to enable the HTML5 player of youtube as your default player.
Just google how to do it as i do not have knowledge of the procedure but i know that it can be done.

Comment: WELL HERE IT IS FOR YOU:
http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: oh, about html5, it's still in beta. It doesn't wrok for all the videos, that's the reason why i didn't use it. It's for every flash player possible, not for youtube only...